# Vanilla JS target href on link with child elements

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to target the `href` of links with a certain class, but when the links contain child elements, it seems the result of `e.srcElement` depends on where in the link you click.

How do I target the href of the parent `<a`-tag, no matter where inside the link I click? Clicking on the circle gives me the actual href value of the link, but clicking on the F gives me "undefined".

[image: The share button]

**HTML Element**

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=myshorturl" class="social-share">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 32 32" style="fill: #7f91a4;" class="at-icon at-icon-facebook"><g><path d="M22 5.16c-.406-.054-1.806-.16-3.43-.16-3.4 0-5.733 1.825-5.733 5.17v2.882H9v3.913h3.837V27h4.604V16.965h3.823l.587-3.913h-4.41v-2.5c0-1.123.347-1.903 2.198-1.903H22V5.16z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></g></svg>
    <span class="sr-only">Share This</span>
</a>
```

**Vanilla JS**

```
var shareButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("social-share");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(shareButtons, function (lnk) {
    lnk.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        e = (e ? e : window.event);
        var t = (e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement);

        console.log(t);
        console.log(t.href);
    });    
});
```

Comment: You have access to the `lnk` variable within the callback...

Comment: Doh'... I feel stupid now!

Comment: It happens to everyone, ☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var shareButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("social-share");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(shareButtons, function (lnk) {
    lnk.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(lnk.href);
    });    
});
```

Within the context of your specific use case, the `lnk` variable is scoped to the `forEach` call closure, and will still be accessable within the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget):

```js
const icons = document.querySelectorAll('.social-share');

icons.forEach(function(icon){
  icon.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  
    // Prevent really going to Facebook
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // Check if currentTarget is the icon
    if (this !== e.currentTarget){
      return;
    }

    console.log(e.currentTarget.href);
  
  // bind icon here so that `this` in the function equals to icon
  }.bind(icon));
});
```

```css
.social-share {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=myshorturl" class="social-share">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 32 32" style="fill: #7f91a4;" class="at-icon at-icon-facebook"><g><path d="M22 5.16c-.406-.054-1.806-.16-3.43-.16-3.4 0-5.733 1.825-5.733 5.17v2.882H9v3.913h3.837V27h4.604V16.965h3.823l.587-3.913h-4.41v-2.5c0-1.123.347-1.903 2.198-1.903H22V5.16z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></g></svg>
    <span class="sr-only">Share This</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Why bind it?  `icon` is scoped to the closure in which you create the event binding.  It is still accessable within the event handler.  Just like in the OP the `lnk` is.

Answer (score -1):

There is probably a better way to do this, but you can achieve that by checking if the target element is the one that you want, and if it is not, start bubbling up until you find it.
Something like:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".social-share").forEach( (e) => {
  e.addEventListener( "click", (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    let aElement = ev.target;
    while(!aElement.classList.contains("social-share"))
      aElement = aElement.parentElement;
    console.log(aElement);
  } )
});
```

This method has its dangers, the same "dangers" associated with `while` loops, but since we're rigging the click event through query selection on a class, as long as the nested children doesn't have the same class name, it will always end where the listener was set it the first place.

You can do the same with your code. I just like the queryselector, and you can easily extrapolate the idea.

Comment: As stated in the comments, they still have a reference to `lnk`.  All this logic is unnecessary

Comment: Aye, indeed. Saw your comment after post :-)